# Find the probability that a random variable is "good" and find the expected value of the number of "good" random variables.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose that $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are i.i.d. continuous random variables. $X_k$ is called good if we have $X_i < X_k$ for all $i<k$.

1) Find the probability that $X_k$ is good.

2) Find the expected value of the number of good random variables. Show that this value approaches infinity when $n \to \infty$.

Please do not give me a full solution first. Just hints. My major issue with this problem is that I do not understand what the question is asking mathematically. So, a random variable is just a function from some probability space to real numbers. What kind of probability density are we assuming on the space of random variables? What is our probability space here?

Comment: What is the probability that $X_2$ is good?  This is just $P(X_1<X_2)$  Can you write the event that $X_3$ is good in a similar fashion?

Comment: @saulspatz: Well, it's going to be $P(X_1<X_3, X_2< X_3)$. Right?

Comment: Yes that's true, but I was thinking along the lines that it's $P(X_1\leq X_2<X_3\vee X_2\leq X_1<X_3)$  In this form, it's easier to see what the value is.

Comment: @saulspatz  Thanks for your help. Why do you want to write it like that? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Because then we see that by symmetry, the probability that $X_n$ is good is $1/n$.  Or for another way of looking at it, what is the probability that $X_n$ is the largest of $n$ i.i.d r.v.'s?  (Note that, since the r.v.'s are continuous, the probability that any two of them are equal is $0$ so we can ignore this possibility.)

Comment: @saulspatz  I don't see the symmetry clearly. :( I mean, For example for $X_k$, we should consider all permutations of $X_1, \cdots, X_{k-1}$. Shouldn't we? Why is it $\frac{1}{k}$ then? And not $\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$?

Comment: No, it's all permutations of $X_1\dots X_k$ and only the ones with $X_k$ last are acceptable.

Comment: @saulspatz: Exactly. So, the $k$-th element in the permutation is fixed. We still need to permute $k-1$ of them. Right? That gives that the probability of $X_k$ being good to be $\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$ according to your analysis if I understood it correctly. Why $1/k$ then? Could you expand your comment please?

Comment: I think I'll write an answer.  Give me a few moments

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we sort the variables $X_1\dots X_k$ in increasing order, there are $k!$ possible orders.  Only the ones where $X_k$ comes last make $X_k$ good.  There are $(k-1)!$ such arrangements.  Since, by symmetry, all orders are equally likely, the probability that $X_k$ is good is $${(k-1)!\over k!}={1\over k}$$

We ignore the possibility that two of the variables have the same value.  Since the X_i are continuous r.v.'s, the probability that two of them are equal is $0.$

The expected number of good $X_k$ is just $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X_k\text{ is good})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{1\over k} = \infty$$

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being so confused at first. Now I understand what you meant by symmetry.

Comment: No need to apologize.  I was glad to help.